# Using the $.proxy command in javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bit of code that has a bit of a foreign syntax to me:

```
$.widget('ui.filterFieldDisplay', $.ui.fieldDisplay, {
setFoo: function() {
  .
  .
  .
  // added the next two lines
  var fooFieldWidgetOptions = fooFieldOptions.widgetOptions;
  fooFieldWidgetOptions['default'] = operator;
  var fooChangeProxy = $.proxy(this.fooChange, this);
  fooFieldWidgetOptions.changeCallback = fooChangeProxy;
}

fooChange: function(fooModel) {
  fooModel.getValue('bar');
  .
  .
  .
}

});
```

Is `fooModel` in this case referenced to the `this` pointer?

I know that the `$.proxy` method binds the `this` pointer to the function, so that it operates within that context.  But I know that `this` doesn't get referenced to `fooModel`.  So my question is: what is `fooModel` and where does it come from?

Comment: i assume the `.`'s is just your way of saying there's code there that you've omitted?

Comment: Yes, the `.` is omitted code for the sake of secrecy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `fooModel` will be whatever was passed as the first parameter to `fooFieldWidgetOptions.changeCallback`

```
fooFieldWidgetOptions.changeCallback("helloWorld!"); // fooModel will be `helloWorld!`
```

All `$.proxy()` did was ensure that `this` inside of `fooChange` will be the same as `this` inside of `setFoo`

Comment: Since, nothing was passed to `fooFieldWidgetOptions.changeCallback`, does that mean `fooModel` is `undefined`?  Is it set to a default value?

Comment: If it is indeed the case that nothing is passed to it, yes, you haven't included that part of your code in your question though so i can't be sure.

Comment: Okay, so is that the only way to pass a variable to `fooChange` in my case? Is there other ways?  I've edited my code to include more details about how it was called in `setFoo`.